# Unable to fetch the title of products from redmart using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Creating a scraper for the purpose of parsing the title of different products from a web-page when I run it, I get nothing. im using the python to get the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen

myurl=Request('https://redmart.com/product/concatenatew2-x2-y2-95192', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
pagehtml=urlopen(myurl).read()
pagesoup=soup(pagehtml,'html.parser')

containers=pagesoup.find_all('div',{'class':'productDetailsWrapper'})
print(containers)
prdtname=container.find_all('div',{'class':'description'})
name=prdtname[0].text
print(name)
```

Comment: You need to render javascript. So either use selenium or scrapy with splash

Comment: you tried and it worked? @Gaur93

Comment: @choopage-JekBao No, if I had tried that I would have written above comment in answer. Using selenium or scrapy with splash is the general approach to scrap javascript rendered content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page loads its data dynamically through Ajax API. If you look to your Firefox/Chrome network inspector, you will see the URLs where the page connects. This example will load all data for beverages in category 'big-beverage-boom' in JSON format (I commented out the URL, from where the page loads all categories):

```
import json
import requests
from pprint import pprint


pagesize = 100
page = 1
category = 'big-beverage-boom'
url = 'https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?pageSize={}&sort=1024&category={}&page={}'

# This will load all categories:
# categories_url = 'https://api.redmart.com/v1.6.0/catalog/search?extent=0&depth=1'
# r = requests.get(categories_url)
# data = json.loads(r.content)

r = requests.get(url.format(pagesize, category, page))
data = json.loads(r.content)

pprint(data)
```

The script outputs:

```
...snip...

   'img': {'h': 0,
           'name': '/i/m/img_1527825363355.jpg',
           'position': 0,
           'w': 0},
   'inventories': [{'atp_lots': [{'from_date': '2018-07-26T16:09:13Z',
                                  'qty_in_carts': 0,
                                  'qty_in_stock': 4,
                                  'stock_status': 1,
                                  'to_date': '2019-11-29T15:59:59Z'}],
                    'atp_status': 0,
                    'delivery_option': 'standard',
                    'limited_stock_status': 0,
                    'max_sale_qty': 48,
                    'next_available_date': '2018-07-26T16:09:13Z',
                    'qty_in_carts': 0,
                    'qty_in_stock': 48,
                    'stock_status': 1}],
   'inventory': {'atp_lots': [{'from_date': '2018-07-26T16:09:13Z',
                               'qty_in_carts': 0,
                               'qty_in_stock': 4,
                               'stock_status': 1,
                               'to_date': '2019-11-29T15:59:59Z'}],
                 'atp_status': 0,
                 'delivery_option': 'standard',
                 'limited_stock_status': 0,
                 'max_sale_qty': 48,
                 'next_available_date': '2018-07-26T16:09:13Z',
                 'qty_in_carts': 0,
                 'qty_in_stock': 48,
                 'stock_status': 1},
   'measure': {'size': 0.0, 'wt_or_vol': '24 x 500 ml'},
   'pr': 103,
   'pricing': {'applicable_discount': 'promo',
               'discounts': {'live_up': {'promo_price': 25.95,
                                         'savings': 12.03,
                                         'savings_amount': 3.55,
                                         'savings_text': '12% OFF',
                                         'savings_type': 1},
                             'promo': {'promo_price': 26.55,
                                       'savings': 10.0,
                                       'savings_amount': 2.95,
                                       'savings_text': '10% OFF',
                                       'savings_type': 1}},
               'on_sale': 1,
               'price': 29.5,
               'promo_id': 188169,
               'promo_price': 26.55,
               'savings': 10.0,
               'savings_amount': 2.95,
               'savings_text': '10% OFF',
               'savings_type': 1},

...snip...
```

For getting titles from the data, you can use:

```
for d in data['products']:
    print(d['title'])
```

This prints:

```
San Pellegrino Sparkling Natural Mineral Water
Pocari Sweat ION Supply Drink
Volvic Natural Mineral Water Case
Pauls Zymil Lactose Free Low Fat Milk
Pocari Sweat ION Supply Drink
MARIGOLD Less Sweet Chrysanthemum Tea
CoCoWater Pure Coconut Water - Case
Coco Life Coconut Water
Perrier Lemon Sparkling Mineral Water
Pokka Premium Afternoon Red Tea
RedMart Coffee Beans
Asian Story Chrysanthemum Tea (Less Sugar) - Case
Yeo's Soya Bean Drink
Pauls Zymil Lactose Free Full Cream Milk
MARIGOLD Low Fat UHT Milk - Case
Gerolsteiner Sparkling Water
100PLUS Tangy Tangerine Isotonic Drink
Vitasoy Chocolate Flavored Soy Drink
Evian Natural Mineral Water
Schweppes Bitter Lemon - Case
H-TWO-O Original Isotonic Drink
Vittel Natural Mineral Water - Case
Pokka Peppermint Green Tea
MARIGOLD Less Sweet Lemon Barley Drink - Case
Pacific Soy Barista Series
Jia Jia Less Sugar Herbal Tea
Dutch Lady UHT Full Cream Milk
Pacific Organic Soy Unsweetened Original Non-Dairy Beverage
Perrier Lemon Sparkling Mineral Water - Case
Pureharvest Organic Oat Milk Non-Dairy
Evian Natural Mineral Water Case
UFC Velvet Unsweetened Almond Milk
Schweppes Slimline Indian Tonic Water
Monster Energy Ultra Sugar Free Energy Drink
Asian Story Chrysanthemum Tea (Less Sugar)
Farmhouse Low Fat UHT Milk - Case
Pokka Straight Red Tea - Case
CocoMax Coconut Water
Bonsoy Organic Soy Milk - Case
YOUC1000 Vitamin Lemon Health Drink
Cowhead UHT Lactose Free Milk
CoCoWater Pure Coconut Water
Fevertree Naturally Light 4's Tonic Water
Pokka Premium Milk Tea - Case
Pauls UHT Low Fat Milk - Case
Twinings Pure Peppermint Tea
Australia's Own Unsweetened Soy Milk
MARIGOLD Less Sweet Lemon Barley
Twinings English Breakfast Tea 25's
Living Planet Low Fat Organic Dairy Milk
Perrier Lime Sparkling Mineral Water
Schweppes Slimline Indian Tonic 12 Per Pack
Blue Diamond Almond Breeze Unsweetened
HOMESOY No Sugar Added Soy Dairy Free Milk
Coco Life Coconut Water - Case
Red Bull Energy Drink
F&N Magnolia Chocolate Flavoured Milk
Lactel UHT Semi-Skimmed Milk
UFC Refresh 100% Natural Coconut Water
Perrier Sparkling Water
MARIGOLD Less Sweet Soya Bean Drink - Case
Wong Coco All Natural Coconut Juice With Pulp - Case
Pokka Nanyang Coffee
Perrier Lime Sparkling Mineral Water - Case
Ice Mountain Sparkling Lemon - Case
Dilmah Premium Quality 100% Pure Ceylon Tea
Vitasoy Original Soy Drink
Dutch Mill Yoghurt Drink with Strawberry Juice
Pauls Chocolate Milk
F&N Magnolia Smoo Chocolate Flavoured Milk
Devondale UHT Skim Milk
Pauls Strawberry Milk
Perrier Pink Grapefruit Sparkling Natural Mineral Water
Pokka No Sugar Oolong Tea
Vitasoy Melon Flavored Soy Drink
Super Essenso MicroGround Coffee - 2 In 1 Coffee And Creamer
Wong Coco All Natural Coconut Juice With Pulp
Perrier Pink Grapefruit Sparkling Mineral Water - Case
Dutch Mill Yoghurt Drink with Blueberry Juice
Ice Mountain Lemon Sparkling Water
CoCoWater Pure Coconut Water
100PLUS Isotonic Drink
Jeju Samdasoo Natural Mineral Water - Case
Red Bull Energy Drink Sugar Free
Super Essenso MicroGround Coffee - 3 In 1
Pokka Chrysanthemum White Tea Case
100PLUS Zero Sugar 6s
Rude Health Ultimate Organic Almond Drink
Three Legs Guava Flavour Cooling Water
Premium Matcha Green Tea
OSK Japanese Green Tea with Brown Rice
MARIGOLD Chocolate UHT Milk - Case
Dilmah Camomile Tea
Rude Health Organic Gluten Free Almond Drink
Twinings Lemon and Ginger Tea
Pocari Sweat ION Supply Drink - Case
CocoMax 100% Coconut Water - Case
YOUC1000 Vitamin Orange Health Drink
F&N Magnolia Smoo Vanilla Flavoured Milk
MARIGOLD Soya Bean Drink
```

Edit:

Redmart have own Github page with useful utilities: https://github.com/Redmart. Worth to check that too.

Comment: how to get the redmart api?

Comment: @Ajai Look at their Github page, maybe you will see something useful: https://github.com/Redmart

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Selenium this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

scrapeLink = 'https://thelinkyouwanttoscrape.com'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get(scrapeLink)
html = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML')
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
titles = soup.find_all('the_tag_that_contains_the_info_you_want')
```

The website, by the way states:

> Without prejudice to the generality of Clause 2.1, you agree not to
>   reproduce, display or otherwise provide access to the Site, App,
>   Services or Content, for example through framing, mirroring, linking,
>   spidering, scraping or any other technological means (including any
>   technology available in the future), without the prior written
>   permission of RedMart.